# RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: ADMINISTRATOR. (discordjs v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have updated to discordjs v14.0.3. (this error was not in v13)

I have a command handler where i can acces the permissions from a command, passed in a array, and i pass through each and check if the message author has the permissions.

```js
command.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has(permission)) {
        const perm_embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("#cf1b1b")
            .setTitle(`[INFO] ${command_name}`)
            .setAuthor({ name: message.author.username, iconURL: message.author.avatarURL() })
            .setDescription(`Aceasta comanda cere urmatoarele permisiuni: \`${command.permissions}\` \nDin pacate, tu nu ai urmatoarea permisiune care este nevoita: \`${permission}\``)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.reply({ embeds: [perm_embed] }).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 2000);
            return;
        });
    }
});
```

command.permissions looks like this: [ 'ADMINISTRATOR' ]
I get this error **ONLY** **when a user that does not have the permissions** run the command. (if i have the permission, it does not throw a error)

> RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: ADMINISTRATOR.

I have double checked and i do not have any typo.

EDIT: I found a hardcoded workaround.

```js
for (const perm of command.permissions) {
    try {
        message.member.permissions.has(perm);
    } catch {
        const perm_embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("#cf1b1b")
            .setTitle(`[INFO] ${command_name}`)
            .setAuthor({ name: message.author.username, iconURL: message.author.avatarURL() })
            .setDescription(`Aceasta comanda cere urmatoarele permisiuni: \`${command.permissions}\` \nDin pacate, tu nu ai urmatoarea permisiune care este nevoita: \`${perm}\``)
            .setTimestamp();

        message.reply({ embeds: [perm_embed] }).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 2000);
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

which just calls the has function on the member permission, so if it throws it goes and says you dont have permission, otherwise it goes on.

But since i want a good and maintainble (and not messy) solution, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Your `command.permissions` should look like this (instead of using strings):

```js
[PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator]
```

and you should import PermissionsBitField from discord.js:

```js
const { PermissionsBitField } = require('discord.js');
```